# How to align text in restructured text so that will be aligned in latexpdf?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, text-alignment

I've tried to write own rst-classes and apply it to H1, H2 (headers like ====== or ~~~~~~~) and it works good when I make html. But in PDF it looks like headers, it is unexpected.

Please help me to solve this problem. I need to provide my report with good title page for my university but I don't know how to do it in ReST.

P.s. Sorry for my english, I'm russian =)

[image]

In the PDF here https://docdro.id/NRaWdDf each part is on its own page, like this

[image]

and the Contents.rst is at https://github.com/greenstm137/RWOfStudents/blob/4c8153969ed4d7e8de937d0ae33ccbaa7af03cdd/source/contents.rst

Comment: If you want fine control over LaTeX formatting, you should write LaTeX directly, not in reStructuredText or ReST that wraps over and hides all the details. There isn't much to discuss as the only feasible way to heavily customize the conversion is to dive into the source code of sphinx, which goes far beyond a normal question here.

Comment: @john-hen where can I find any info how to use these "raw" LaTeX commands in sphinx?

Comment: @john-hen okay, thank you, I'll try if noone helps me

Comment: @john-hen Do you know can I solve this problem using "styles"? My scientific supervisor said me to try this way, but I didn't find any suitable info how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add raw latex code to center it. Try this:

```
|lstartcenter| My Text is Centered! Cool! |lendcenter|

.. |lstartcenter| raw:: latex
     \begin{center}

.. |lendcenter| raw:: latex
      \end{center}
```

This code sets a start and an end tag with "raw:: latex" which inserts raw latex code if you compile it to latex.

"|lstartcenter|" starts making it centered, while "|lendcenter|" ends centering it.